# Install Visual Studio Express 2013 Windows Desktop and Web Application

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I already installed the `Visual Studio Express 2013 For Windows Desktop` to my system and now I want to install the `Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web Application`.

Problems:

1. It is possible to install both Visual Studio versions on the same system?
2. If I installed both software on the same system than it may occur any issues?

Comment: This question has been asked before (though I can't find the duplicate right now), but your answers are: 1. Yes. 2. No.

Comment: Thank you. @ChrisF. You tried it in past?

Comment: Yes, I have installed the different Express editions in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you install both version it neither affect your machine nor slower your machine .

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed install both versions side-by-side.  In fact, Visual Studio is designed such that you can install not only different editions within the same version (*e.g.*, VS 2013 for Desktop alongside VS 2013 for Web), but **also different versions** (*e.g.*, a VS 2013 edition alongside a VS 2015 edition).

Check out the [Installing Visual Studio Versions Side-by-Side](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609.aspx) article on MSDN.  The only stipulation that Microsoft makes is that versions should be installed *in the order in which they were released* (*e.g.*, install VS 2013 **before** VS 2015 products).

On my personal development machine, I have VS 2012 Desktop, 2013 Desktop, *and* VS 2015 for Web installed without any issues whatsoever.  I routinely run different versions at the same time as well.